# PHP won't display result of echo

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a problem, when I try with this code without hosting I'm getting result but when I try it on host php won't display result, I know Select * is not good nowadays but if you can please help.

This is screen how it looks like:

[image]

Here is code:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
   if (!$conn) {
die("no connection".mysql_error());
}

$db = mysql_select_db("db_name");
 mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn);
```

I'm using this code on HTML:

```
          <thead> 
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>სახელი</th>
            <th>ტექსტი</th>
            <th>პატარა ტექსტი</th>
            <th>სურათი</th>
            <th>წაშლა</th>
          </tr>
       </thead> 
       <tbody>
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM news";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>".$data['id']."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$data['name']."</td>";
              echo "<td>".substr($data['article'], 155,300)."</td>";
              echo "<td>".substr($data['text'], 155)."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$data['img']."</td>";
              echo "<td><a href='del.php?id=".$data['id']."' onClick=\"javascript:return confirm('ნამდვილად გსურს წაშლა?');\">წაშლა</a></td>";
              echo "</tr>";} 
            ?>
   </tbody>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: can you make sure that your php works in general? create a new page and do <?php echo 'hello world';

Comment: how is named  you code files?

Comment: I think you are not using .php file here. Please make sure your html code is in .php extension file

Comment: @Dimi I did but It isn't working ... just showing me in source my that code... scaisEdge, filename.php

Comment: newly setup LAMP??? or any other combination ??

Comment: @ZuraGabodze it means that you are not running php parser. You will need to setup LAMP or something of that sort (ex: XAMPP)

Comment: I have XAMPP but when I use XAMPP and localhost:8080 it works fine, when I upload it on HOST it isn't working